# How to comment within an HTML attribute?

Tags: html, comments

The final (closing) angle bracket in the code below is not interpreted as closing the `<input>` element:

```
<input type='text' name='name' <!-- id='name' -->>
```

I thought this was a valid way to comment out this attribute but Google Chrome, Firefox and Notepad++ (color coding) all suggest that this is not the way to go.

I used <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> in Notepad++ to do this.

Then what is the proper way to comment out this `<id>` attribute?

Comment: Why comment? remove if its not in use

Comment: Just remove the id attribute?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

HTML provides no way to place a comment inside a tag.

---

If you are generating the HTML from a template / programming language, then you can use features of that to comment something out.

For example, in Template-Toolkit:

```
<input type='text' name='name' [%# id='name' %]>
```

or PHP:

```
<input type='text' name='name' <?php # id='name' ?>>
```

---

If you are using HTML 5 then you could (as an ugly hack) use a data attribute to "comment" out entire attributes.

```
<input type='text' name='name' data-comment-id='name'>
```

Comment: that really is a bummer. It would be nice to temporarily disable attributes like "class" or "id" in some cases.

Comment: Thx, I'm actually learning PHP but this one was hand-written!

Comment: The initial goal was to save myself typing by using the Notepad++ shortkey for commenting out stuff. Works great for CSS and PHP but apparently not always for HTML :-(

Answer (score 3):

I usually just put `_x` at the end of the attribute name. Then the attribute is ignored because it's unknown. So if I wanted to comment out the `id` attribute from this element:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
```

I would change it to this:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id_x="name">
```

This also has the advantage of being able to search for "`_x=`" to find all commented attributes.

Comment: Obviously this trick should only be used when developing and "commented" attributes shouldn't be left in production code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='text' name='name' <?php  /* id='name' */ ?> >
```

you may use this it will not be interpreted when viewing the source info

Answer (score -2):

I agree, that you should not use comments at this place. That said, the following should work in Chrome, Firefox and IE:

```
<input type="text" %id="test1"% class="test2">
```

[image: Inspect element in Google Chrome]

[image: Inspect element in Firefox]

Comment: That puts `<input type="text" %="" %id="test1">` in the DOM, which is horrible.

Comment: In Chrome it renders `<input type="text" %id="test1" % class="test2">`.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to comment a line in HTML5 and don't use

```
<!-- Html comments -->
```

You can use

- aria-label

for example:

```
 <button aria-label="Close" nclick="myDialog.close()">X</button>
```

or

```
<button aria-label="This button close the popup" nclick="myDialog.close()">X</button>
```

Since there is nothing to indicate that the purpose of the button is to close the dialog, the aria-label attribute is used to provide a label to any assistive technology or simply comments.